# One-sample or two-sample t-test for sample lack of variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, t-test

I want to compare two independent samples to check whether they're significant different. One sample group only has the **mean** and lacks information about the variance. And the other sample has 3500 data entries.

I've done one-sample t-test, based on the lack of variance. Due the other sample is not population, I'm afraid the result might be incorrect.

Any suggestion on which test should I choose?

Comment: You have no hope unless you can assume some specific relationship between the two samples.  After all, under the conditions you have specified, the variance of the first sample group could literally be anything.  Please, then, edit this post to provide more information about your situation.